# What is the probability that in a 3-by-3 grid of playing cards sans Jacks, no adjacent cards add to 13 and no Kings or Queens appear?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The rules to a solitaire-type card game, named *Yenta*, are as follows:

> Remove the Jacks from a standard deck of playing cards and shuffle the remainder. **Then, place nine cards face up in a 3-by-3 grid in reading order** (that is, left to right and top to bottom). The goal of the game is remove all cards from the playing field. **You may remove a pair of cards if they are orthogonally adjacent (but *not* diagonal) and add to 13, with Aces being counted for 11. Pairs which fit the criteria are placed in the discard pile.**
>
> **If no cards fit these criteria, you may pair a King or Queen with an orthogonally adjacent card and set it aside, replacing both cards on the playing field.** You must then at some point pair a Queen or King, respectively, with an orthogonally adjacent card which adds to the aforementioned card's "complement" (i.e., the card which, when added to the other, will yield 13). For example, if a King and an Eight are paired up and set aside, then at some point, a Queen and a Five must be paired up, whereupon all four cards may be placed in the discard pile.
>
> After removing cards from the playing field, two more are added from the draw pile, and the player may decide where each card is placed.
>
> The game is won when all 48 cards are placed into the discard pile. **The game is lost when no legal moves may be played. That is: when there are no orthogonally adjacent cards which add to 13 and there is not a King or Queen on the playing field;** or there are no orthogonally adjacent cards which add to 13, but there *is* a King or Queen on the playing field, but in pairing it with any available cards, it would eliminate the possibility of pairing any reserved cards with their complements. For example, if all 4 Kings are set aside and paired with Tens, and the only move would be to pair a Queen in the corner with an orthogonally adjacent Nine or Four, then the game is lost, because in so doing, the Queen, the card it's paired with, one King, and one Ten would not be able to be discarded.

My question is this: what is the probability that the game is automatically lost when the cards are dealt? For the sake of convenience, I have bolded the relevant rules above, but for the sake of clarity (and at the risk of redundancy), I will repeat them down below.

> What is the probability of drawing 9 cards from a deck of playing cards (with Jacks removed) and placing them in a 3-by-3 grid in reading order such that
>
> > A) no two orthogonally adjacent cards add to 13 (with Ace valued at 11), and
> >
> > B) no Kings or Queens appear in the grid?

First, a point of order - the reason I am so insistent that they be placed in reading order is simply to drive the point home that the player cannot choose where the cards go. It may well be in reverse reading order or in a spiral, all that is important is that the player *cannot* look at a card and place it in a strategically advantageous position that they would not otherwise be able to do.

Now for the math. The easiest component by and far is to find the answer to the smaller question, "What are the odds that you draw 9 cards from a deck of cards sans Jacks and do not draw any face cards?". Namely,

$$P(X_{QK})=\frac{40!39!}{48!31!}=\frac{310726}{1905803}\approx.1630$$

We can then figure out the probability that, in this configuration, the center card is not adjacent to its complement:

$$P(X_{Center})=\frac{44*43*42*41}{47*46*45*44}=\frac{12341}{16215}\approx.7611$$

an arbitrary edge card is not adjacent to its complement:

$$P(X_{Edge})=\frac{44*43*42}{47*46*45}=\frac{13244}{16215}\approx.8168$$

and an arbitrary corner card is not adjacent to its complement:

$$P(X_{Corner})=\frac{44*43}{47*46}=\frac{946}{1081}\approx.8751$$

My troubles here stem from the fact that, individually, all of these are Boolean and independent. We don't care if the a corner card is the Ten of Spades and whether it's adjacent to the Two of Hearts and Nine of Clubs or the Eight of Clubs and the Five of Diamonds. All we care is whether or not they add to 13. However, in combining all these, it *does* suddenly begin to matter. Each card has a knock-on effect that influences the next.

Furthermore, in the case of the edges and corners, each edge/corner has the potential but not the guarantee to affect the probability of another edge/corner. For instance, when placing the cards, if the top-left corner is an Ace and the top-right corner is a Two, that means that there's one less Two in the deck that can be adjacent to that Ace.

I just can't seem put all the pieces together as is necessary. I would appreciate any help with this from anyone more experienced in matters of combinatorics than I. Thank you for reading!

Comment: By Monte Carlo simulation, the probability that $9$ cards drawn at random from a deck with the Kings, Queens, and Jacks removed and placed in a 3 by 3 grid have no adjacent pairs summing to $13$ is approximately $0.355$.  So the overall probability of success is about $0.163 \times 0.355 = 0.0483$.